Problem: Peg Solitaire Solution with Backtracking in C
I'm working on a backtracking solution to solve peg solitaire game. My problem is that it keeps printing possible solutions and it never stops. The recursive base case is that the program must stop when there is only one pin in the center; while it does not, it must keep printing only the right solutions or right pin movements.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH (1000)

int history[MAX_LENGTH][7][7];
int history_length = 1;

int verify(int mtrx[7][7]);
int move_is_valid(int mtrx[7][7], int i, int j);
int move_pin(int mtrx[7][7], int i, int j, int direction);
void add_to_history(int mtrx[7][7]);
void show(int mtrx[7][7]);
int play(int mtrx[7][7]);

int main()
{
    int mtrx[7][7] = {
        { -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1 },
        { -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1 },
        { -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1 }
    };

    show(mtrx);
    
    if (play(mtrx))
        printf("Jogo Concluido!!!");
    else
        printf("Erro!!!");

    return 0;
}

int verify(int mtrx[7][7])
{
    int total_pins = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            if (mtrx[i][j] == 1)
            {
                total_pins++;
            }
        }
    }
    return (total_pins == 1 && mtrx[3][3] == 1) ? 1 : 0;
}

int move_is_valid(int mtrx[7][7], int i, int j)
{
    if (i < 0 || i >= 7 || j < 0 || j >= 7 || mtrx[i][j] == 0 || mtrx[i][j] == -1) {
        return 0; // invalid move
    }
    if (i > 1 && mtrx[i - 1][j] != 0 && mtrx[i - 2][j] == 0) {
        return 1; // valid upward move 
    }
    if (i < 7 - 2 && mtrx[i + 1][j] != 0 && mtrx[i + 2][j] == 0) {
        return 2; // valid downward move
    }
    if (j > 1 && mtrx[i][j - 1] != 0 && mtrx[i][j - 2] == 0) {
        return 3; // valid move to the left
    }
    if (j < 7 - 2 && mtrx[i][j + 1] != 0 && mtrx[i][j + 2] == 0) {
        return 4; // valid move to the right
    }
}

int move_pin(int mtrx[7][7], int i, int j, int direction) {
    
    if (direction == 1) {
        mtrx[i][j] = 0;
        mtrx[i - 1][j] = 0;
        mtrx[i - 2][j] = 1;
        add_to_history(mtrx);
        return 1;

    } else if (direction == 2) {
        mtrx[i][j] = 0;
        mtrx[i + 1][j] = 0;
        mtrx[i + 2][j] = 1;
        add_to_history(mtrx);
        return 1;

    } else if (direction == 3) {
        mtrx[i][j] = 0;
        mtrx[i][j - 1] = 0;
        mtrx[i][j - 2] = 1;
        add_to_history(mtrx);
        return 1;

    } else if (direction == 4) {
        mtrx[i][j] = 0;
        mtrx[i][j + 1] = 0;
        mtrx[i][j + 2] = 1;
        add_to_history(mtrx);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}

void add_to_history(int mtrx[7][7]) {
    if (history_length < MAX_LENGTH - 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                history[history_length][i][j] = mtrx[i][j];
            }
        }
        history_length++;
    }
}

int undo_move(int mtrx[7][7]) {
    if (history_length > 1) {
        history_length--;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                mtrx[i][j] = history[history_length][i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void show(int mtrx[7][7])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            if (mtrx[i][j] == -1)
                printf("#");
            else if (mtrx[i][j] == 0)
                printf(" ");
            else
                printf("o");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int play(int mtrx[7][7]) {

    //printf("history_length: %d\n", history_length);
    
    if (verify(mtrx)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        show(mtrx);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                int direction = move_is_valid(mtrx, i, j);
                if (direction != 0) {
                    move_pin(mtrx, i, j, direction);
                    sleep(1);
                    if (play(mtrx) == 1) {
                        return 1;
                    } else undo_move(mtrx);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


Have you tried to debug your program? For example by stepping through the code line by line in a debugger while monitoring variables and their values.

@chqrlie fixed your algorithm in an answer below, but as an aside to that, storing the entire board in the history seems wasteful as you could store just the coordinates of the three positions involved in the move taken - that would be enough info to reverse it.

@500-InternalServerError: good point. Hint added in my answer.  Note that the whole board state can fit in a 64-bit integer, yet I have not found an elegant and efficient way to take advantage of this more compact representation.

Thank you all for your help! With your and @chqrlie comments, I noticed that during the implementation I missed some details, which led to the problem mentioned. I learned a lot from this experience, thank you very much for your help!!!


... and it never stops

That sleep() really slows things down.
Missing return
Save time, enable all compiler warnings. What value do you expect to return from move_pin() when none of the if()s are true?
Fixing move_pin(), removing sleep(), adding some performance improvements (like adding if (mtrx[3][3] != 1) return false; to the beginning of verify() and omitting many intermediate prints) resulted in Erro!!!.  So code may still have other logical failings, but at least it completes in under a minute.

Yeah, the sleep calls definitelly slow things down a bit, but after @chqrlie suggestion I notice that one of the problems was that I forget to use a condition to use only pins on move_pin function, not forgetting to mention other problems like the history management. But, thanks a lot for your help too!!!

There are multiple problems:

the function move_is_valid seems incorrect: the final return 0; statement is missing if the move is invalid from an internal cell.

you show every move and wait for 1 second... it will take a very long time to reach a solution.

removing the show and sleep calls, the code runs for a few seconds and gives up, printing Erro!!! after trying 62052193 moves.

the reason it does not find a solution is it does not try every possible move: all cells are enumerated at each step, but only the first possible move is tried.  You should try every possible move from every populated cell at each step before backtracking to the previous step.


After correcting these errors, further investigation shows that your backtracking logic is flawed:

you save the new matrix after each move, then increment history_length
if all moves failed, you decrement history_length and restore the corresponding entry.  This is incorrect as you merely restore the position after the last move at this step, not the initial position before this move.  You should save to history the position before the move.

With this fix, a solution is found after trying 7667770 moves and 0.989 second on my laptop.
Here is the modified version:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH  (7*7-4*2*2-1-1)

int history[MAX_LENGTH][7][7];
int history_length;
long long int moves_played;

int verify(int const mtrx[7][7]);
int move_is_valid(int const mtrx[7][7], int i, int j, int direction);
void move_pin(int mtrx[7][7], int i, int j, int direction);
void add_to_history(int const mtrx[7][7]);
void show(int const mtrx[7][7]);
int play(int mtrx[7][7]);

int main(void)
{
    int mtrx[7][7] = {
        { -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1 },
        { -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1 },
        {  1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  1,  1 },
        {  1,  1, 1, 0, 1,  1,  1 },
        {  1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  1,  1 },
        { -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1 },
        { -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1 }
    };

    if (play(mtrx)) {
        printf("Jogo Concluido! %lld moves tried\n", moves_played);
        for (int i = 0; i < history_length; i++)
            show(history[i]);
        show(mtrx);
    } else {
        printf("No solution: %lld moves tried\n", moves_played);
    }
    return 0;
}

int verify(int const mtrx[7][7])
{
    int total_pins = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (mtrx[i][j] == 1) {
                total_pins++;
            }
        }
    }
    return (total_pins == 1 && mtrx[3][3] == 1);
}

int move_is_valid(int const mtrx[7][7], int i, int j, int direction)
{
    if (i >= 0 && i < 7 && j >= 0 && j < 7 && mtrx[i][j] == 1) {
        switch (direction) {
        case 1: // up
            return (i > 1 && mtrx[i - 1][j] == 1 && mtrx[i - 2][j] == 0);
        case 2: // down
            return (i < 7 - 2 && mtrx[i + 1][j] == 1 && mtrx[i + 2][j] == 0);
        case 3: // left
            return (j > 1 && mtrx[i][j - 1] == 1 && mtrx[i][j - 2] == 0);
        case 4: // right
            return (j < 7 - 2 && mtrx[i][j + 1] == 1 && mtrx[i][j + 2] == 0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void move_pin(int mtrx[7][7], int i, int j, int direction)
{
    mtrx[i][j] = 0;
    switch (direction) {
    case 1:
        mtrx[i - 1][j] = 0;
        mtrx[i - 2][j] = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        mtrx[i + 1][j] = 0;
        mtrx[i + 2][j] = 1;
        break;
    case 3:
        mtrx[i][j - 1] = 0;
        mtrx[i][j - 2] = 1;
        break;
    case 4:
        mtrx[i][j + 1] = 0;
        mtrx[i][j + 2] = 1;
        break;
    }
}

void add_to_history(int const mtrx[7][7])
{
    if (history_length < MAX_LENGTH) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                history[history_length][i][j] = mtrx[i][j];
            }
        }
        history_length++;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "history too short\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int undo_move(int mtrx[7][7])
{
    if (history_length > 0) {
        history_length--;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                mtrx[i][j] = history[history_length][i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void show(int const mtrx[7][7])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (mtrx[i][j] == -1)
                printf("#");
            else if (mtrx[i][j] == 0)
                printf(" ");
            else
                printf("o");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int play(int mtrx[7][7])
{
    if (verify(mtrx)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (mtrx[i][j] == 1) {
                    // try all moves from every populated cell
                    for (int direction = 1; direction <= 4; direction++) {
                        if (move_is_valid(mtrx, i, j, direction)) {
                            moves_played++;
                            add_to_history(mtrx);
                            move_pin(mtrx, i, j, direction);
                            if (play(mtrx))
                                return 1;
                            undo_move(mtrx);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Note these improvement directions:

the length of the history array need not be larger than 31: one less than the number of pins on the board.
verify can be simplified substantially: instead of counting the pins, it should just test that history_length == 31.
copying to and from the history array can be done faster with memcpy
the type for the matrix cells can be changed to int8_t or char to reduce memory use and bandwidth.
the intial tests in move_is_valid can be removed.
as suggested by @500 - Internal Server Error, storing the whole board in the history seems wasteful, just storing the position and contents of the 3 modified cells would suffice to revert the change.


Thanks a lot for your help! I've learned a lot from your perspective and it is totally right. I'm still learning backtracking and it is very challenging at times, but its been fun. Once again, thanks bro!!!
